# How to publish a message from Unity3D to ROS node?

Tags: ros, rosbridge, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to send over msg of type string from Unity to my ROS node that contains the subscriber topic, over rosbridge_websocket.

I have already tried the following:

[**ROS-Sharp**](https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp):
With ROS Sharp I have issues with UWP (Universal Windows Platform) build. The ROSBridelib library is written in order to target .NET 4 and above, however, they are using websocketsharp library websocket-sharp library we are using does not support UWP.

To accommodate that, I used directives:

```
#If WINDOWS_UWP    

#endif
```

and also tried using the ROSbridgeLib directly as an imported package instead of using it as a .dll file.

Related: https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/issues/33

But I still got the error:

```
Assets/RosSocket.cs(201,45): error CS1644: Feature **null propagating operator** cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification
```

[**Unity ROS**](https://github.com/michaeljenkin/unityros): This is what I have done while using Unity ROS. https://answers.ros.org/question/278819/unable-to-publish-message-to-ros-bridge-from-unity/

I did have some partial success using Unity ROS, in publishing a message topic from ROS to Unity3D, however the other way round has not been achieved.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279912/how-to-publish-a-message-from-unity3d-to-ros-node?/) by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2018-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-16**:
I can't help you, but if I could, I was probably going to need a lot more information. "has not been achieved", "struggling for weeks" get the point across that you're encountering difficulty, but without more info on what *exactly* you have done, used, what failed, what you observed, etc, it's ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-16**:
.. really hard to help you.

At the moment your post is equivalent to: "my car doesn't work, please help me".

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-17**:
And a related github issue over at `ros-sharp`: [siemens/ros-sharp#33](https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/issues/33).

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-01-17**:
The reason for posting this question is to ask the community if there is any other alternative apart from the ones i have been using. If you see the linked ros answer question, one of the contributor suggested me to use the ros-sharp, so been working on that, however no success with that yet.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-01-17**:
It's related not duplicate. If I can solve the issue https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/issues/33 I will add that as a solution here.
For the time being, I am looking into alternatives if any/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used [Unity ROS](https://github.com/michaeljenkin/unityros) finally to have this solved which supports Universal Platform Support; which implies it can be used for VR devices, and similar application.

I had to make some changes to the data model that is sent over the rosbridge. Kindly follow Issue [#11](https://github.com/michaeljenkin/unityros/issues/11) for further details.

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2018-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0